# recognize my face opencv python3

Tags: python, opencv

I do some research in this forum and i hope nobody asked the same question. 
For my school project i'm trying to create a python program in my raspberry pi 3 for detect face and for recognize my own face. I can detect face but i don't how can i do for recognize my face and write my name in the screen when the camera see me. 
Should i create a xml cascade with photos of me ?
Here is my code for detect face :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_haar.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my first thread in this forum if i do something wrong i'm sorry and say me what i do wrong. If my english is bad i'm sorry and say me if it's true.

Comment: Not sure about any easy way of making your code to recognize your face, probably with some machine learning (you can try sklearn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).
For writing text, just  :
    cv2.putText(img, 'text', (x_position, y_position ), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)

Comment: Thank you , I'm going do some research with scikit